# Importing orders to Magento - product_options

Tags: orders, import, mysql, magento-1.9

I've been tasked with importing from a non Magento store into Magento 1.9. We have over 236k orders that need to be imported. So far I've successfully written services (c#) to manage importing customers, categories, attributes and products directly into mysql. Now I need to do the orders. However, I'm stuck on what the information is in the product_options field that is serialized.

```
a:1:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:2:{s:3:"qty";i:1;s:7:"options";a:0:{}}}
```

Can anyone point to somewhere that defines what each item is (s:15, a:2, s:3, etc) or explain to me what each item that needs to go into the serialization?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you posted is the [serialized](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.serialize.php) version of the array

```
array (
  'info_buyRequest' => 
  array (
    'qty' => 1,
    'options' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
)
```

`a:1` means that what follows after that is an array with 1 element.
`s:15` means that what follows after that is a string with 15 characters
`i` means that what follows is an integer.

I don't know the equivalent of the serialize function from php to C#, but if you only have simple products in the orders you need to import then I suggest using the same string as above and change only the `1` from `i:1` to the quantity of the product in that specific order.

If you have configurable products or custom options it's going to be horrible. In this case the `options` section can have a lot of different values.